# BigCommerce access the users language code and currency in the template file

Tags: bigcommerce

I am wondering if it is possible to get the current users language code and currency code `product.html` template file. Like using a {{ }} encapsulated variable.

My current `product.html` look like this, but I would like to access the currency and language of the current user in this page somehow, please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the currency code with `{{currency_selector.active_currency_code}}`. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/theme-objects/currency_selector

I don't believe you can get the language directly via Handlebars, but you may be able to use some indirect route looking at different properties in the settings object. For example, `{{settings.country_code}}`. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/theme-objects/settings

Comment: I have another question, is it possible to get the cart id of the current customer as a handlebar? Or some other reference to the cart of the current customer?

Comment: By the way is there a way to get the cart id of the current customer who is accessing the product details page? Using a handlebar